# Display alert message when range gets overridden - Excel Office js

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

Before clear a range, if the range as values I would like to prompt this window. Does the office js API supports this functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't find an Excel.js API that directly supports this, but it's an interesting idea. Consider recommending this at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

As a possible workaround, consider reading the range first to see if it has values. If it does, your code can use the [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) to create your own prompt. The code in the dialog could use the `messageParent` API to tell the task pane what the user's response was and then your code on the task pane can react to that.